# Gitlab CI Pipeline Authentication with AWS MFA

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, cicd, amazon-ecr, multi-factor-authentication

I am working on a cloud project in AWS where we have MFA enabled on the account level and we are self-hosting gitlab on EC2.

I have a requirement to allow for gitlab users to push images into AWS ECR via CI Pipeline which is typically a straight forward process, however, we are running into an authentication issue and would love some assistance.

Below are the following steps that *should* work.

1. Create Identity Provider in IAM console.
2. Create IAM role to allow specific actions to Gitlab CI/CD (I am using the AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess permission)

   2b. Edit the trust relationship and add the Gitlab project reference. Trust relationship policy looks like  below.

   ```
   {
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [{
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Principal": {
         "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::<account-no>:oidc-provider/gitlab.com"
       },
       "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
       "Condition": {
         "StringEquals": {
           "gitlab.com:aud": "https://gitlab.com (self hosted url)",
           "gitlab.com:sub": "project_path:groupname/projectname:ref_type:branch:ref:main"
         }
       }
     }]
   }
   ```
3. Update ".gitlab-ci.yml" as below to retrieve credentials

   Created a project on (self hosted url)

   Project included Dockerfile as below

   ```
   =====
   FROM nginx:alpine
   COPY ./public /usr/share/nginx/html
   =====
    A folder called "public" containing custom index.html file
    ".gitlab-ci.yml" file with below contents
   =====
   variables:
   DOCKER_REGISTRY: <account-no>.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
   AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: us-gov-west-1
   APP_NAME: aws-cli-image
   DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
   ROLE_ARN: arn:aws:iam::<account-no>:role/GitLab_Role
   ```

   ```
   assume role:
   id_tokens:
   GITLAB_OIDC_TOKEN:
   aud: https://gitlab.com
   image: 
   name: amazon/aws-cli
   entrypoint: [""]
   services:
   - docker:dind
   before_script:
   - amazon-linux-extras install docker
   - aws --version
   - docker --version
   ```

   ```
   script:
   - >
   export $(printf "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=%s AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=%s AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=%s"
   $(aws sts assume-role-with-web-identity
   --role-arn ${ROLE_ARN}
   --role-session-name "GitLabRunner-${CI_PROJECT_ID}-${CI_PIPELINE_ID}"
   --web-identity-token ${GITLAB_OIDC_TOKEN}
   --duration-seconds 3600
   --query 'Credentials.[AccessKeyId,SecretAccessKey,SessionToken]'
   --output text))
   - aws sts get-caller-identity
   - docker build -t $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$APP_NAME:$CI_PIPELINE_IID . 
   - aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $DOCKER_REGISTRY
   - docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$APP_NAME:$CI_PIPELINE_IID
   ```
4. After committing the files, Gitlab CI/CD pipeline started, however, the pipeline failed with error "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity operation: Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity".

Apparently, the runner that we created was created on the server, thus having the server's permission and not the newly created "Gitlab_Role." We are unable to assign this role directly to the EC2 instance because it was created with Web Identity and not an AWS Service.

How can we get the runner to properly execute with the proper permissions?

I followed all steps identified in the detail. We are stuck due to the permissions on the role not being enforced in gitlab. It is being overwritten with the server role which does not have a web identity enabled.

Comment: Are you sure you setup the identity provider using the URL of your self-hosted instance and not `gitlab.com` and the token's `aud` value in your YAML is the same as in your IAM policy?

Comment: Hi there - In response, yes the gitlab.com was a place holder where in my actual yml file, I referenced the self-hosted instance's url. The token's aud value is the same as the IAM policy. Thank you for taking a look.